# Converting a floating value to Months and days

Tags: date, julia

Just wondering if anyone knows how to convert a floating value to months and days. For example if I ended with 25.6 as a floating value. I want to convert the 25 part into months (25 months) and 0.6 part in days (something like 17 days)

```
 val = 25.6
 md = monthday(val)
 #out >  (1.0, 25.6)
```

I tried the `monthday` function but its results seem to be not what I am after. Next, I want to add it into some `DateTime` value such as `today() + md`

Comment: Just to confirm, are you looking for a way to split a floating point number into an integer and a fractional component? Like what [`modf`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Math.modf) does?

Comment: Yeah, That would work I guess. What I finally want is, if the value is 6.5, Then today (06/01/2021) + some function(6.5) will end with 21/06/2021. 0.5 converted to 15 days and 6 converted to 6 months. SO you would end in June 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
julia> function f(x)
           fm, m = modf(x)
           Day(Int(round(30.416*fm))) + Month(Int(m))
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(25.6)
25 months, 18 days
```